# JOLT tranform elements based on key

Tags: json, transform, jolt

I am trying to find out correct JOLT specification file for below:

Input file:

```
{
  "network": "A",
  "ips": {
    "subnet1": "1.1.1.1",
    "subnet2": "1.1.1.2",
    "subnet3": "1.1.1.3",
    "subnet4": "1.1.1.4"
  }
}
```

Output file:

```
{
  "allValues": [
    {
      "network": "A",
      "ips": {
        "subnet1": "1.1.1.1",
        "subnet2": "1.1.1.2"
      }
    },
    {
      "network": "A",
      "ips": {
        "subnet3": "1.1.1.3",
        "subnet4": "1.1.1.4"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Based on subnet values, I want to group the IPs(subnet1 and subnet2 in one) and (subnet3 and subnet4 in another), while all should have network value(`A`).

Can somebody please help.

Comment: Your input file isn't valid JSON, fields in an object must have unique names. Any way you can get the format into something like:

   {
     "network": "A",
     "ips": [
       {"subnet1": "1.1.1.1"},
       {"subnet2": "1.1.1.2"},
       {"subnet3": "1.1.1.3"},
       {"subnet4": "1.1.1.4"},
       {"subnet2": "1.1.1.5"},
       {"subnet3": "1.1.1.6"},
       {"subnet1": "1.1.1.7"}
     ]
   }

Comment: @mattyb Thanks for pointing out, I have corrected the question. I want to group the ips based on subnet. Need JOLT specification file for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you know which subnets belong together (`subnet1` and `subnet2` for example), you can use something like the following:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "ips": {
        "subnet1": "allValues[0].ips.subnet1",
        "subnet2": "allValues[0].ips.subnet2",
        "subnet3": "allValues[1].ips.subnet3",
        "subnet4": "allValues[1].ips.subnet4"
      },
      "network": "allValues[0].network",
      "@(0,network)": "allValues[1].network"
    }
  }
]
```